# How can i use PHP explode to create HTML table from text file with a space in between each word

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a text file with 3 columns split with spaces that contains the following:

```
word1 word2 word3
word4 word5 word6
word7 word8 word9
```

I have the following PHP that turns my text file into a table, however it puts each line of the text file into one table cell, i want it to put each word into a table cell.

```
<?php
         $tdcount = 1; $numtd = 3; // number of cells per row
         $str = "<table class=\"table table-hover table-striped\">
                                         <thead>
                                         <th>colum1</th>
                                         <th>colum2</th>
                                         <th>colum3</th>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>

     ";
         $f = fopen("/text.txt", "r");
         if ( $f === FALSE ) {
         exit;
                }
         while (!feof($f)) {
             $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f));
             $row = current ( $arrM );
             if ($tdcount == 1)
                 $str .= "<tr>"; $str .= "<td>$row </td>";
             if ($tdcount == $numtd) {
                 $str .= "</tr>";
                 $tdcount = 1;
             } else {
                 $tdcount++;
             }
         }
         if ($tdcount!= 1) {
             while ($tdcount <= $numtd) {
                 $str .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; $tdcount++;
             } $str .= "</tr>";
         }
         $str .= "</tbody></table>";
         echo $str;
         exit;

?>
```

I have tried playing with  explode line by changing the , to a space however it doesn't work:

```
$arrM = explode(" ",fgets($f));
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading each line and then exploding it, read it as a CSV file with a space delimiter (using `fgetcsv()`), make sure each row has the 3 results (althoug it doesn't cater for more) then `implode()` each row with the `<td>` tags needed and add this to the result...

```
$str = "<table class=\"table table-hover table-striped\">
                                         <thead>
                                         <th>colum1</th>
                                         <th>colum2</th>
                                         <th>colum3</th>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>

     ";
$f = fopen("/text.txt", "r");
if ( $f === FALSE ) {
    exit;
}
while ( $row = fgetcsv($f, null, " ") ) {
    // Ensure all rows have at least 3 cells
    $row = array_pad($row, 3, "");
    // Output data in a row
    $str .= "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $row). "</td></tr>".PHP_EOL;
}
$str .= "</tbody></table>";
echo $str;
```

which (with an extra partial data record) gives...

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                         <thead>
                                         <th>colum1</th>
                                         <th>colum2</th>
                                         <th>colum3</th>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>

     <tr><td>word1</td><td>word2</td><td>word3</td></tr>
<tr><td>word4</td><td>word5</td><td>word6</td></tr>
<tr><td>word7</td><td>word8</td><td>word9</td></tr>
<tr><td>word10</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lines in the file are really separated by spaces the following should work and create what you are looking for.

```
?>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
<th>colum1</th>
<th>colum2</th>
<th>colum3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  
while (!feof($f)) {
    $arrM = explode(" ",fgets($f));
    $row = current ( $arrM );
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($arrM as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
    }  // end of the foreach
    echo '</tr>';
}  // end of the while
echo '</tbody></table>';
exit;
```